# i am using iframe form miniclip.com. i need my own leaderboard. how should i implement this?

Tags: php, mysql, shockwave

iframe code is

```
<iframe src="http://www.miniclip.com/games/london-2012-olympic-games/en/webgame.php" frameborder="0" style="border:none;" width="590" height="443" scrolling="no"></iframe><br /><a href="http://www.miniclip.com/">Play Games on Miniclip.com</a>
```

Now when a user finishes the game . its score should be submitted to my own leader board.
HELP?

Answer (score 0):

Unless Miniclip has specifically implemented some way of letting you do this, this isn't possible.

Comment: thanks duskwuff
suppose i download flash game file with extension .swf
can i put mmy own leader board into it using php mysql 
plz provide be detail answer.

Comment: No, you cannot. You'll have to make your own game.